# Gparted: Need to move unallocated space out of /dev/sda2 partion to /dev/sda1 to increase root size but options are grayed out

Tags: linux, partitioning, ubuntu-18.04, gparted

Due to some reason my `root` (`/dev/sda1`) partition got entirely used up. Probably I installed some thing in it mistakenly, to the point that the OS won't boot. So I created a live Gparted USB from an Windows 10 PC to create a new space out of `/home` and add it to `/dev/sda1` so that the problem of freeing up space in `root` resolves.

This is my `df -h` pic taken from Ubuntu recovery mode:

[image]

And the Gparted live screenshot:

[image]

[image]

But, in order to increase `root` partition size, I need to get the unallocated space out of `dev/sda2` and put it below `/dev/sda1` which is the root. But, I can't do this since every other option except `New` is grayed out when I right click on the unallocated space!

How do I then add the root partition size if it's grayed out?

I also tried doing `swapof -a` from the Ubuntu recovery mode but that did not help. It's now in a situation where I can't do anything without either freeing up space on root or increase its size. I tried some methods to free space in `root` but that didn't help.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Gparted with the branch of `/dev/sda1` expanded.

Comment: That is not expandable in Gparted.

Comment: Sorry, meant `/dev/sda2`.

Comment: There's the imgur [link](https://imgur.com/a/ETrXGNj)

Answer (score 0):

You only have 3.73 GB unallocated in `sda2` that you could use top,
which is not a lot.

I suggest to first reduce `sda7` so as to enlarge the unallocated space that
follows it, then reduce `sda2` to the minimum and move it down
so the unallocated space now follows `sda1` and it becomes possible to enlarge it.

If `sda2` doesn't allow reducing, move `sda7`, `sda6` and `sda5` (in this order)
to the bottom of `sda2` so the unallocated space is moved to the top.
Now you may be able to enlarge `sda1`.

For an example of the process, see the article
[Moving Space Between Partitions](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dmoving-space-between-partitions).

I strongly recommend taking good backups before doing that.

Comment: I apologize for this much late reply. I was able to make plenty amount of free space but couldn't move it below root.  Since I had to get rid of the old desktop, I just reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 over the 18.04 keeping the home partition safe. That way I was able to recover all my files.